# OraOLEDB ConnectionString doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oledb, windows-7-x64

I have the following ConnectionString:

```
<add name="ConnectionStringRWeb" connectionString="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=XX;User Id=web;Password=web1;OLEDB.NET=True;SPPrmsLOB=True;PLSQLRSet=True" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

When i try to open the connection,  I get the following error:

```
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
```

What could be the cause of this? It was working fine before.

**EDIT** restarting the service doesn't fix the problem. I tried twice.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have admin access to Oracle Database?
Can you post the alert file log with complete error here?

Your conString looks like correct. Maybe the error is inside you database.

Comment: Where can i find the alert log fole? I have the problem only with one PC. If the database has errors than it should'n work for the second PC or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you asked and you gave the answer (`ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress`) as far as visible. This ORA code is usually given when the process itself is not ready for a connection as stated within this code. Got this error only once and it was my fault because the Database (Windows service) was in startup and an init phase after starting the db.
Oracle Database must start up properly---Then, you can use it.

Comment: I started the DB Windows servise manually but still same error